# Allow only positive number OR empty space

Tags: java, regex, validation, input

My requirement is that user should not be allowed to enter negative number in my Java application.
I need to check if input field is entirely empty or only positive integer.

What I have is

```
/^[\s\d]*$/
```

Comment: could you provide the way you retrieve the data? I have a suspicion regex is not the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This allows digits (integer) or no digits at all (empty) `/^\d*$/` with no signs, no dots.
Your regex instead allows digits and spaces interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String str = "12 ";
boolean matches = str.matches("[\\p{Digit}\\s]+");
System.out.println("matches = " + matches);
```

And the result is:

```
matches = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    String inField = "1245"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d*|\\s*)$");
    boolean isCorrect = p.matcher(inField).matches();
    System.out.println(isCorrect);
```

see http://ideone.com/hwj5iV